# AngularJS post model to a json file using $http.post()

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

I'm very new in AngularJS. I want to post registration data to a json file. Post request is working correctly,but data is not writing to file. I can't understand that position. Is there something wrong with my post request code? And how can I fix that? Thanks!

```
 var regModel = {
    FirstName: 'Someone',
    LastName: 'Somebody',
    Address: 'somewhere',
    Email: 'something@gmail.com'
};

$scope.insertUser = function () {
    $http.post('../DB/users.json', regModel).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, your post request will have your regModel object in the content of your request. On the server side, you can get the body or content and then write it to file.

Comment: It means I can't write to a file in client side, yeah?

Comment: I am unaware of any known way on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write directly on a file located on the server from the client. 
As willwin.w said, your data `regData` should be transmitted with the request. But you will have to direct your ajax request toward a server side script like PHP, ASP, etc. This script will then have to get the data passed in the ajax request and write them in a file or a database.